# How to import expandable table into Google Sheets?

Tags: html, google-sheets

I am trying to import NFL playoff stats from ESPN using ImportHTML. The problem is that https://www.espn.com/nfl/stats/player/_/stat/receiving is an expandable table that uses JavaScript so ImportHTML only pulls data up to the "see more" section.

Is there a way around this?

Formula I am using: =IMPORTHTML("https://www.espn.com/nfl/stats/player/_/stat/receiving","table",1)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it directly: as you noted, when `IMPORTXML` fetches the page the data is not on the page yet. It is loaded from the backend only when you click the Show More button. `IMPORTXML` cannot click buttons and load data after that.

Luckily, the data on the page is loaded from a publicly accessible API: https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/common/v3/sports/football/nfl/statistics/byathlete?region=us&lang=en&contentorigin=espn&isqualified=false&page=1&limit=50&category=offense%3Areceiving&sort=receiving.receivingYards%3Adesc . When you click the button, the website loads another page of data from the same API.

To load all data you will need to use a custom Google Apps Script function and use it in the spreadsheet via `=fetchData()`:

```js
function fetchData() {
  let url = "https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/common/v3/sports/football/nfl/statistics/byathlete?region=us&lang=en&contentorigin=espn&isqualified=false&page=1&limit=50&category=offense%3Areceiving&sort=receiving.receivingYards%3Adesc";
  const players = [];
  const rows = [];

  while (url) {
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    const data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    players.push(...data.athletes);
    url = data.pagination.next;
  }

  rows.push([
    "Name",
    "Team",
    "POS",
    "REC",
    "TGTS",
    "YDS",
    "AVG",
    "TD",
    "LNG",
    "BIG",
    "YDS/G",
    "FUM",
    "LST",
    "YAC",
    "FD"
  ]);

  players.forEach(player => {
    const row = [];
    
    row.push(
      player.athlete.displayName,
      player.athlete.teamShortName,
      player.athlete.position.abbreviation,
    );
    player.categories.forEach(category => {
      if (category.name === "receiving") {
        row.push(...category.values)
      }
    });
    rows.push(row);
  });

  return rows;
}
```

Notes:

1. In the script I have tried to replicate the structure of the page. Still, there are some differences: rank is relative and depends on the sorting and I am not sure what GP is.

   [image: Exported data example]
2. This API is not guaranteed to stay available. They can change its format or restricted unauthorized access.
3. This script can be extended to run on schedule or directly from the Google Apps Script editor.